# Can a gamma-ray burst affect the same place of the space twice times?

Tags: special-relativity, astrophysics, astronomy, relativity, gamma-rays

I know that the space-time has curvature. Also I have 
basic knowledge about the gamma-ray bursts.

I would like to know if a same pulse of GRB can affect the same place of the space  twice times. Is it impossible? Thank you.

Comment: You might need to be precise about the dimensions of the same "place".

Comment: I accept your words (critic) @Countto10 , thank you and thanks to who answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gamma ray burst is a electromagnetic signal, so the question is can be re-written as *"Can a light signal arrive at one point at two or more times?"*

And the answer to that question is "Yes", we [see light signals from distant quasars along different paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_Cross) due to gravitational microlensing all the time, and when there are more that one distinct images (as opposed to a continuous smear), the paths can have different travel times (the minimum time requirement is local).